# How to change plot background color in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

Is there a way to change the background color of a plot window in NetLogo?

(I want turtles to be black and white, and I'd like plot pens for statistics on the two kinds of turtles to match their colors.  A white pen is not visible on a white background, obviously.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetLogo has not built-in way to change the background color of a plot. Arguably, this is something it should have. If you feel strongly enough about it, I would suggest sending a feature request to `feedback@ccl.northwestern.edu` or even [opening an issue directly on GitHub](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues?state=open).

Now, in the meanwhile, is there a way around it? Well, I feel almost dirty for even suggesting it, but you *could* do something like this:

Create a new plot pen of the color you wish your background to be, and set it to "line mode". This pen has to be the first one in your plot pen list so it's drawn before the other pens. (This might require deleting your other pens and recreating them, as NetLogo doesn't have an easy way to reorder plot pens, I think.)

Now put the following in your pen's **update commands**:

```
plot-pen-reset
let y plot-y-min
while [ y <= plot-y-max ] [
   plotxy plot-x-min y
   plotxy plot-x-max y
   set y y + 0.05
]
```

This will draw lines, one by one, to fill your background. Depending on the size of your plot on the screen, you might want to play with the "interval" (`0.05` here) to find the biggest value that doesn't leave white lines.

Be warned: this will slow down your model. If your plot axis are never rescaled, however, maybe you can get away with putting the code in your pen's **setup commands** so it's only executed once.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas! (@NicolasPayette).  (Hello from your Lisp-using UNCC/NEH friend.)  Perfect.  This works.  It does slow the model down, as you said, but I can use it.  More than that, I know that there is no built-in solution now.  I will probably submit a feature request.  I think a case can be made that it allows better communication in some cases.

Comment: Hey, hello! Funny how a description like "Lisp-using UNCC/NEH friend" uniquely identifies you!